# Last Time Stamp not within valid period

Tags: objective-c

Am rather newbie to Objective C (from Java background):

I got the following code to check if the last time stamp are within the minimum period, how do I do the opposite? E.g. I want to check if the last time stamp is NOT within a valid period, the valid period are in seconds.

[lastTimestamp timeIntervalSinceNow] > -MINIMUM_TIME

Answer (score 1):

This seems too obvious:

```
if ([lastTimestamp timeIntervalSinceNow] <= -MINIMUM_TIME)
{
    // execute some code
}
```

Where `MINIMUM_TIME` is a `NSTimeInterval` variable, representing the time you want to check against.

Comment: If I take the current time that I put into lastTimestamp and then get -12.xxx since 12 seconds as past since I updated lastTimestamp vs the current time, I then compare that with MINIMUM_TIME that is an int variable with a value of 120 seconds, the result is always NO (boolean false) not sure what is wrong there since I expect it to b YES (boolean true)

Comment: You need to post more of your code around the comparison.  Edit your original question, copy and paste in your code.  Make sure your code is indented 4 spaces.